# MSI: cannot uninstall Software

Tags: registry, windows-installer, uninstallation

I installed my product 'Only for me' and then 'For all users'. The result is: they installed in parallel.
I uninstall all using mciuu2.exe, registry cleaner.

I can install the product, then I uninstall it and receive the error:
Cannot open key: UNKNOWN\Components........ Verify that you have sufficient access to that key, or contact your support personnel.

I have checked:  this key is in

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\UserData\S-1-5-21-1829244499-511431514-1402587311-16639\Components\E37A0663FBF638215564F5AAEB259058

Other users dont see it.

How I can repair uninstaller?

Comment: These guys did a pretty good analysis. Tried any of these?  http://www.okino.com/conv/changing_windows_registry_permissions.htm

Comment: Thank you! Can you write you message and I will mark it as Answer?